# The model directive may only occur once per document (adding buttons to lists problem) ASP.NET MVC Core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to display a button because I need to add new information but there is a list within the file and it is not working

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC and C#.

It is something like this:

**HTML File:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Clients>


<table class="table" id="Tabla4">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CODE)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CODE)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My controller method:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    List<Clients> clients = dbContext.GetClients().ToList();
    return View(clients);
}
```

I want to add this in my HTML file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CODE" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CODE" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CODE" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NAME" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NAME" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NAME" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add this:

```
@Model MyApplication.Models.Clients
```

I get this error:

> The model directive may only occur once per document

How can I solve it?

---

EDIT:

My Client Model is this:

```
public class Clients{
 public int CODE {get; set;}
public string NAME {get; set;}

}
```

If i put the button inside the HTML File it throws and error:

```
   @model IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Clients>
    
    
    <table class="table" id="Tabla4">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CODE)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CODE)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="CODE" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="CODE" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="CODE" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="NAME" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="NAME" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="NAME" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It says:

> IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Clients> does not contain a
> definition CODE and no accesible extension method CODE
>
> IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Clients> does not contain a
> definition NAME and no accesible extension method NAME

---

EDIT #2

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CODE" class="control-label"></label>
                <input name="CODE" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="NAME" class="control-label"></label>
                <input name="NAME" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

EDIT #3:

Now it is throwing this error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**, in the foreach part:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Clients>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CODE" class="control-label">Code:</label>
                <input name="CODE" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="NAME" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                <input name="NAME" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table" id="Tabla4">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CODE)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CODE)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Image:
[![image][1]][1]

This is my Controller Create HTTP METHOD:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind] Clients clients)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbContext.InsertData(clients);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(clients);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET **Core** MVC - please use the `asp.net-core-mvc` tag to make this clear!

Comment: Why do you want to place two `@Model` lines in your view? What type is the model in your document/view?

Comment: @marc_s sorry, my bad :(

Comment: @Progman what do you mean by "type", My Clients model contains 2 things: CODE and NAME

Comment: @programming_amazing I mean the type of the model you are calling the document/view with. You can use only one `@Model ...` line (most likely near/at the top) to indicate something like: "This document/view use a model of the type `YourChoosenType`". Using two `@Model` lines doesn't make sense because there is only one value and you get the error message as expected if you add two `@Model` lines.

Comment: @Progman I wanted to display a list and a button to trigger an event in controller file . I need the list because i will create the tuple based on the data shown in that list. Do you get me?

Comment: @programming_amazing Then the line `@Model IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Clients>` or even `@Model IList<MyApplication.Models.Clients>` is correct, as that is the value you are using in the `return View(clients);` line. Delete the `@Model MyApplication.Models.Clients` line to get rid of the error message "The model directive may only occur once per document".

Comment: @Progman take a look, pal. I have edited the question. If i delete Model MyApplication.Models.Clients and try to add the button, it throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `asp-for="..."` when the model/value you are using does not have these properties. Your model is defined as `IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Clients>` as the value for the view is a `List<MyApplication.Models.Clients>` object. When you use `<input asp-for="CODE">` it looks for a property `CODE` inside the `IEnumerable<...>` type. However, this interface does not have such a property.

In your case you don't need `asp-for=""`. Instead you can use a "normal" `<input>` tag with the `name="..."` attribute you want, depending on the `Create()` action you have defined. The code can look like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="CODE" class="control-label">Code:</label>
    <input name="CODE" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

That way the HTTP Request will have the field name `CODE` in the POST body or GET URL parameter list, depending on how you send the form. ASP.NET will automatically fill the values into the parameters of your `Create()` action for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, pal. It does make sense to me

Comment: Take a look, i have edited my question. It should trigger the Create [HTTP POST] method in the controller file, right?

Comment: I believe you need the `method="post"` attribute to send a `POST` request. Otherwise it would be a `GET` request.

Comment: I do not fully understand that: isnt it performing a POST REQUEST by just using <form asp-action="Create">? Should i edit that and put something like this: <form asp-action="Create" method="post">?

Comment: @programming_amazing Yes. You can check the generated source code in your browser and should see something like `<form action="Create" method="post">...</form>`. That way a POST request is send.

Comment: Getting rid of asp-action="Create" does not mean it wont trigger the Create HTTP POST in Controller?

Comment: @programming_amazing Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-form-tag-helper on how the form tag helper supports you in creating HTML forms. When you don't have `asp-action="..."` or `action="..."` in your `<form>` tag, your browser will not know where to send the form to (or maybe send it to the current URL instead).

Comment: Take a look, there exist a new error. I have edited my question.

Comment: @programming_amazing That would be a different problem/question, but the problem with NullReferenceExceptions is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it